# Trouble with internal apache rewrite on hosting server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting, internal

I'm having trouble with an internal rewrite on a hosting server. This works perfectly on my development and testing server, but when the .htaccess is ported to the production shared host, the internal rewrite is not happening.

.htaccess is being read (verified)
RewriteRule with a 'redirect' works, but internal rewrite does not. The URL in the browser shows the correct friendly url but the internal rewrite is not happening, and I'm ending up on the home page.

Here is a piece of the Rewrite:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/$                  index.php?pid=3 [QSA,L]
```

So my URL in the browser will show www.mydomain.com/contact/ but I'm at the home page.

If I change RewriteRule ^contact/$ to ^contact/$ http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?pid=3 I get redirected, but that is not what I want.. I want the internal rewrite.

Looking at the logs, I'm not receiving a 404, so it appears that I'm just hitting the base / root of the directory.

Any ideas??

Thanks!
hanji

UPDATE: received an email from the hosting provider, stating that they're unfamiliar with my 'style' of rewrites and this is what they suggested:

```
RedirectPermanent /contact/ http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?pid=3
```

Um... idiots. I'm hoping we can ID what is preventing my rewrites from working so I can get back to them with something to look at. I'm guessing it's a configuration issue with Apache? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Trying your `RewriteRule ^contact/$ index.php?pid=3 [QSA,L]` rule, my Apache tried to make an internal redirect to `/full/filesystem/path/to/document/root/index.php`, which of course does not map to the correct location when used as a URL path. Changing the target to `/index.php?pid=3` seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried changing ^contact/$ /index.php?pid=3 [QSA,L] and that does not work. Same result.